# Is it better to use Update or execSQL to update data on SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sql-update, android-sqlite, sp-executesql

I saw in a tutorial a code updating data from a SQlite database using execSQL:

```
    String update = "UPDATE FRUIT SET COLOR=? WHERE ID=?";
    myDatabase.execSQL( update, new Object[] {"RED", 7});
    Cursor cursor = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM FRUIT;", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
            String color = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLOR"));

            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Name: " + name + ", color: " + color);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

but, I read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execsql_3) in the oficial documentation of Android:

[image]

The code using **execSQL** worked but it's better to use **update** or I can still use **execSQL** since it worked? What's better for good practice? Since this tutorial is from a trustworthy source, why are they using **execSQL**?

Comment: I wasn't able to execute an update/insert/delete in a database transaction using rawQuery/execSQL. I always had to use the convenience methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue/warning regarding using `execSQL` may be for a few reasons, one of them being that you do no get anything returned when using execSQL, whilst the convenience methods return potentially useful values.

`insert` will return a long  containing the id of the inserted row else -1.
 `update` and `delete` return the number of affected rows.

Using the convenience methods also reduces the chance of making typing errors by build the underlying SQL, adding the keywords and enclosing strings and for some importantly offering a level of protection against SQL injection (`execSQL`'s 
 **bindArgs** also offers protection against SQL Injection, likewise with `rawQuery`).

However, there are limitations and sometimes the use of execSQL/rawQuery becomes necessary for some more complex situations.

Comment: If you were to use one of them, which one you would chose and why?

Comment: Convenience methods.

Comment: So, I have to do a presentation about those methods. Do you think I could say " we can use execSQL but Android's oficial documentation says that We SHOULD use the oficial methods (update/delete/...)" ?